# Help to understand Joomla! code

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5

The code line is:

```
    $lists['published'] = JHTML::_('select.booleanlist', 'published' , 
'class="inputbox"', $row->published);
```

I found it at 
http://www.phpeveryday.com/articles/Joomla-Component-Creating-Form-Input-Data-at-Back-End-P44.html

You can do a search on the page for the code segment.

The problem is with JHTML::_( parameters ).

I looked into this Joomla! documentation page:
http://docs.joomla.org/API15:JHTML/, but as a novice Joomla! programmer I couldn't understand the parameters. Can anyone help me understand the parameters please?

I thought this forum would be quicker in response than the mentioned site.

ADDED LATER:
Following two lines are from:

http://www.phpeveryday.com/articles/Joomla-Component-Saving-Data-to-Database-P45.html

```
$checked    = JHTML::_('grid.id', $i, $row->id);

$published  = JHTML::_('grid.published', $row, $i);
```

What is the explanation of grid.id and grid.published please?

Answer (score 1):

> $lists['published'] =
>   JHTML::_('select.booleanlist',
>   'published' , 'class="inputbox"',
>   $row->published);

Its nothing but html generation for boolean type data. This will generate the html of radio list with two options `yes` and `no`.

- First argument is html for which type
  of element
- Second is name of radio
  list
- Third is any attributes need to
  add to html of radio list
- Forth is for the value which should be selected

> $checked = JHTML::_('grid.id', $i,
>   $row->id);

This is used to show the check-boxes according to id.
Second argu is the counter of row, and third argu is the id value of the chekbox.

> $published = JHTML::_('grid.published', $row, $i);

This is used to show cross and right mar in grid display in back-end. Cross mark when value is 0(no) and right mark is for 1(Yes).
Second argu s for name of field/element and third is the current value of that element.

Comment: from where can i know the arguments of JHTML::_(arguments), from the API or what else place? URL plz. As to grid.id and grid.publisher, u gave the explanation, but what is the source to know them as a Joomla! progrmmer?

Comment: @sof_user : Goto JoomlaRoot / libraries / joomla / html / html.php and html folder at same place.

Comment: really can't understand anything from there.. I was going through ' Learning Joomla! 1.5 Extension Development Creating Modules, Components, and Plug-ins with PHP ' from Pack-Pub . The book didn't give me such info as far as I had read. Do u know what is the real way to find the ans of such probds without asking in forums>

Comment: @sof_user : check this URL http://api.joomla.org/Joomla-Framework/HTML/JHTML.html Probably this may help you. Otherwise practice makes man perfect.